# htaccess Redirect Causes Errors

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm working on a website that has been built sloppily.

The website is filled with regular links that are translated into the corresponding `.php` pages by the `.htaccess` page.

This is it:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^koral/(.*)/$ page.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^koral/(.*)$ page.php?name=$1

RewriteRule ^(.*).html/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ cat.php?cat=$1&page=$2&order=$3&dir=$4
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ cat.php?cat=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html$ product.php?cat=$1&product=$2

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

First of all, I would love some help regarding whether or not this page has everything it should. I've never messed with it before.

Secondly and my main issue, if, for example, I would write the address `www.thewebsite.com/foobar.html`, it would be translated into `www.thewebsite.com/cat.php?cat=foobar` by the `.htaccess` page, and it would give a database error (and reveal information about the database).

I've put a check into `cat.php` which checks if the category exists, but I can't redirect the user to the 404 error page. There's a page called `404.shtml` in the website, but redirecting the user to it causes the `.htaccess` to just change it again to `cat.php?cat=404`.

Is the way they used the `.htaccess` page normal? Should I change this system?
And how are users sent to error pages? From what I understood the server should be doing it on its own?

I would love some clarification... There is some much about this subject I don't understand.

Update:

This is my new .htaccess page

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^error.php?err=(.*)$ Error$1.html

# Only apply this rule if we're not requesting a file...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
# ...and if we're not requesting a directory.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]

RewriteRule ^koral/(.*)/$ page.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^koral/(.*)$ page.php?name=$1

RewriteRule ^(.*).html/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ cat.php?cat=$1&page=$2&order=$3&dir=$4
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ cat.php?cat=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html$ product.php?cat=$1&product=$2

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

Because the redirecting is in the code and the user cannot see it, I allowed myself to write the link in a non-clean way. I tried turning it into a clean URL but the following does not do anything:

```
RewriteRule ^error.php?err=(.*)$ Error$1.html
```

Can someone please help me understand why? I thought since error.php is a real page, I should put it before the conditional but it didn't work. BTW, I saw in an article about .htaccess that the page should start with `Options +FollowSymLinks`. It seems to me that everyone sort of has their own way of writing it. Is there a guide or something like that, which I can be sure is authentic and covers all the bases there is about .htaccess?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using rewrite rules to work around links to `.html` pages that don't exist is unusual in my experience, but it's really just a different take on "pretty" URLs, e.g. `www.thewebsite.com/foobar/` gets routed to `cat.php?cat=foobar` on the backend.

Your 404 issue is different. You need to be able to display error pages.

One option here is to rewrite requests *as long as they don't request an existing file*. This is very common for serving up static content like images, CSS files, and the like. To do this, you can use the [`-d` and `-f` options to `RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), which apply when requesting a directory and file respectively:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Only apply this rule if we're not requesting a file...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
# ...and if we're not requesting a directory.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ cat.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now, requests to `404.shtml` should go through, because you're requesting an existing file on the filesystem.

Note that the `RewriteCond`s only apply to the single `RewriteRule` that immediately follows. For additional `RewriteRule`s, also include additional `RewriteCond`s.

Comment: Your code does not affect the performance of the page but I can't seem to get it to work. Am I doing something wrong? I have written my problem above. Please help! Thank you.

Comment: @user2422544, the `RewriteCond`s apply only to the single `RewriteRule` afterwards (the [`C` flag says to chain](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_c), and the [`L` flag says to end the ruleset](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)). You need to add the conditions to *each rule* where they should be applied. I will update my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is wrong anywhere. Literal dot needs to be escaped using otherwise it will match any character. Also it is better to use `L` and `QSA` flags to end each rule properly.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^koral/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ cat.php?cat=$1&page=$2&order=$3&dir=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ cat.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ product.php?cat=$1&product=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry but adding the [L,QSA] does not work. It messes the whole thing, I think it just sends it to the first line every time.

Comment: Which URL didn't work for you? Where did you place above .htaccess? Are there other rules also? Just be assured `[L,QSA]` is not the problem but `not so well defined problem` may be.

Comment: Okay, it's working now. It was just a matter of taking the third rule below the forth.
Btw, I have written my final problem and a few questions. I appreciate your help so far greatly but can you have a look? Thank you!